# How to export a single email folder from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, export

We want to export a single email folder for a colleague to work on from a Gmail account that ideally we'd like to export as Excel or similar.

I know that you can download entire inboxes with IMAP/Thunderbird, etc. but is there a way of selecting a single file?

Comment: Gmail uses labels, not folders. It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

You should try GrexIt (http://grexit.com) - it lets you share a Gmail label with any other Gmail or Google Apps user. Very easy to setup, and works completely off IMAP. There's a free plan, and a 30 day free trial for all paid plans.

Disclosure: I'm the Founder of GrexIt.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout

1. Deselect all.
2. Scroll down the list to Select **Mail**.
3. In the sub option, 'All Mail' is selected by default. Select only
   the required label/folder.
4. Proceed to next step.
5. Create Export.

The resulting zip file will contain your emails in a MBOK file, which you can open with any text editor such as Notepad++.